# FetchType.EAGER para FetchType.LAZY

Tags: banco-de-dados, jpa-2.0, ejb

Estou com o seguinte problema, o sistema todo usa uma relação, Eager, mas para uma consulta em especifico não quero trazer todas as relações no banco, pois ficaria muito pesado o processo, somente para essa consulta consigo mudar o parâmetro para Lazy?

Estou usando EJB,JNDI, JPA e EclipseLink

Comment: Estou com um problema parecido. Não consigo mudar o fetch mode em tempo de execução (estou usando o Hibernate).<br>
Mas para tentar te ajudar te passo estes links (desculpe não achei material em português):<br>
http://hantsy.blogspot.ru/2013/12/jpa-21-entity-graph.html<br>
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-profiles<br>

Answer (score 3):

Nativamente não existe como deixar dados como Lazy, ainda.

Abaixo faço sugestão de como contornar ou conviver com esse problema.

## Boa Prática 1

---

Dependendo do relacionamento não existe problema em deixar como EAGER o relacionamento. Algo como:

```
@OneToMany(fetchType = EAGER)
List<Email> emails; // sendo que aqui teria no max 3 emails

@OneToMany(fetchType = EAGER)
List<PerfilUsuario> perfil; // um usuário teria uns 2 perfis como Gerente e Usuario
```

Note que para coleções que terão poucos dados não tem problema em deixar EAGER. Agora o problema é se isso vira prática e todos os atributos ficam como EAGER, isso detonará com a memória do servidor.

## Boa Prática 2

---

O melhor é que seus relacionamentos LAZY, os que terminam em *Many, sejam sempre LAZY. Para isso bastaria deixar seus relacionamentos como:

```
@OneToMany
List<Email> emails;

@OneToMany
List<PerfilUsuario> perfil;
```

E a consulta ser realizar através de JPQLs como:
    select p from Pessoa p join fetch p.Emails e

Você busca apenas o necessário para ser exibido na tela. Por que essa solução é uma boa prática:

1. Melhora a performance da consulta no banco de dados. A quantidade de dados a ser trazidas será menor.
2. Otimiza a banda entre servidor e banco de dados. O consumo é menor pois a quantidade de dados retornada é menor
3. Diminui o tempo que o JPA leva para transformar o resultado da query em objetos
4. Ocupa mesmo espaço na memória do servidor.

Bem, tem mais vantagens mas só com essas eu creio que já dá para mostrar que buscar apenas o necessário já é a melhor solução.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer uma consulta com JPQL selecionando apenas as entidades necessárias.

Com JPQL você pode forçar joins para relacionamentos LAZY ou selecionar apenas alguns atributos.

Em último caso, use uma query nativa.